# Bringing data attribute over from another table Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, foreign-keys

I have these three takes that are not linked by foreign keys.  (some sample data below).

A dealer has customers with assigned customers numbers.  however, another dealer can have a customer with the same number but they are not the same customer.

```
|---------------------|    |---------------------|   |---------------------| 
|   DISTINCT_DEALER   |    |  DISTINCT_CUSTOMER  |   |    CUSTOMER_SALES   |
|---------------------|    |---------------------|   |---------------------| 
|      d_id   (pk)    |    |       d_id          |   |        d_id         |
|---------------------|    |---------------------|   |---------------------| 
|    dealer_address   |    |     dealer_name     |   |   customer_number   |
|---------------------|    |---------------------|   |---------------------| 
|    dealer_city      |    |   customer_number   |   |    total_sales      |
|---------------------|    |---------------------|   |---------------------| 
|    dealer_state     |    |    customer_name    |
|---------------------|    |---------------------| 
|    dealer_zip       |    |    customer_email   |
|---------------------|    |---------------------|
```

Sample Data:

[image]

[image]

Whats the best way to approach this?

I have this query right now

```
select cs.d_id, cs.customer_number, cs.total_sales from cs_sales cs where cs.d_id in
(select dc.d_id from dcust dc where dc.d_id = 'A00007');
```

It does exactly what I need to with the exception of returning the customers name in the table so that i can match the sales for that customers per that dealerships.  ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your subquery in the from clause, and adding another field, like so:

```
select cs.d_id, cs.customer_number, cs.total_sales, subquery_dc.customer_name
from cs_sales cs,
       (select dc.d_id, dc.customer_name from dcust dc 
        where dc.d_id = 'A00007') subquery_dc
 where cs.d_id in subquery_dc.d_id;
```

This creates a virtual table with the d_id, and the customer_name fields pulled from the dcust table.  Then, you can join to these specific records like you were before, and also pull back the customer_name field for display.

Comment: getting an error at `where cs.d_id in subquery_dc.d_id`

Comment: @jesus2kus, what kind of error?  Can you post it here?